# Intellij: show translated string inline in normal Java project like it does in Android projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea, internationalization

In Android projects if you use i18n and have the Strings in an external xml file, Intellij recognizes them if you reference it and shows them instead of the call to the MessageBundle/getString:

What you see:
[image: Showing resolved translated Text in Android project]

Actual code behind:
[image: Actual code behind the line]

Is it somehow possible to use that feature in a normal Java project (a Spring app in my case) where we use a custom lookup, like:`i18n.get("test.text")`